# cdr reports shows nothing in freepbx12

Tags: mysql

I have freshly installed freepbx12 on Ubuntu 14. Now, cdr reports won't show anything. In MySQL, the cdr is empty and the cel table has the data of the call.

Answer (score 0):

These are steps to find where is the problem:

- In the web interface, when you go to `FreePBX System Status` it must show this:

[image]

if the *MySQL* row is OK and green then your FreePBX is connected to the database. Otherwise you have to verify which user / password you have configured in the database and which one is configured in FreePBX.

---

- Check what is configured in the menu Settings / Advanced under the title `Remote CDR Database`.

---

- In Console go to */var/log/asterisk* and check for ERRORS or WARNINGS in the "full" files, like these:

  ```
  [2016-02-02 10:23:57] ERROR[20647] res_config_pgsql.c: PostgreSQL RealTime: Failed to connect database asterisk on 127.0.0.1
  [2016-07-22 15:40:21] WARNING[30780] res_config_pgsql.c: PostgreSQL RealTime: Couldn't establish connection. Check debug.
  ```

---

- Open the Asterisk console and make a call. Check if the ERROR appears.

---

- Go to /etc/asterisk and check this :

  - Contents of file *cdr_mysql.conf*
  - Contents of file *res_odbc_additional.conf*

Comment: in menu select "Call Detail Recording" 
Call Detail Recording    
[*] cdr_adaptive_odbc                     
[*] cdr_custom        
[*] cdr_manager       
[*] cdr_syslog             
     --- extended ---             
[*] cdr_csv                     
[*] cdr_odbc            
XXX cdr_pgsql             
XXX cdr_radius            
[*] cdr_sqlite3_custom          
XXX cdr_tds                      
--- deprecated ---              
XXX cdr_sqlite

Comment: in cdr_mysql.conf
[global]
hostname = localhost
dbname=asteriskcdrdb
password = pass345@#()
user = dbcdrasterisk
userfield=1
;port=3306
;sock=/tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: in res_odbc_additional.conf
[asteriskcdrdb]
enabled=>yes
dsn=>MySQL-asteriskcdrdb
pooling=>no
limit=>1
pre-connect=>yes
username=>asteriskuser
password=>passNvmaQ6l

Comment: in /var/log/asterisk/full - i don't see any error logs
in FreePBX System Status all is green

not sure what happen here but i can see in cel tables i can see logs.

Comment: when i reload the asterisk i see logs below.

[2016-08-18 13:27:10] NOTICE[18173]: res_odbc.c:1546 odbc_obj_connect: Connecting asteriskcdrdb
[2016-08-18 13:27:10] NOTICE[18173]: res_odbc.c:1578 odbc_obj_connect: res_odbc: Connected to asteriskcdrdb [MySQL-asteriskcdrdb]
[2016-08-18 13:27:10] NOTICE[18173]: res_odbc.c:933 load_odbc_config: Registered ODBC class 'asteriskcdrdb' dsn->[MySQL-asteriskcdrdb]

Comment: [2016-08-18 13:27:10] ERROR[18173]: cdr_custom.c:99 load_config: Unable to load cdr_custom.conf. Not logging custom CSV CDRs.
    -- Reloading module 'cel_custom.so' (Customizable Comma Separated Values CEL Backend)
[2016-08-18 13:27:10] ERROR[18173]: cel_custom.c:90 load_config: Unable to load cel_custom.conf. Not logging CEL to custom CSVs.
    -- Reloading module 'cel_manager.so' (Asterisk Manager Interface CEL Backend)
    -- Reloading module 'cel_odbc.so' (ODBC CEL backend)

Comment: Is the user `dbcdrasterisk`with password `pass345@#()`a valid user in the database?

Comment: yes its valid. the cdr table is now woking in mysql. i can see the call logs. but in cdr reports in GUI still nothing.

Comment: any one, i really need your help with this